# split SQL field

Tags: mysql, database

We are exporting data from one application to another and have a problem where 5 fields are stored within 1 field in the old application we are getting rid of.

example of Field 'notes' contents,

> Job ID: 1234 Job Type: Maintenance Contract: 4321/M - Maint - Computer Site: fred @ House Task Performed: Check HDD

How can i split this into different fields for Job ID, Job Type, Contract, Site and Task Performed, we have over 10,000 records in this format that need to be split to import to the new database

Comment: Well luckily that is not that many records.  I would honestly look at putting together a script in your language of choice to extract this data.  Doing so in MySQL is possible, but would likely require a cumbersome use of substring operations.

Comment: Have a read of [this thread](http://www.dbforums.com/mysql/1655041-reverse-operation-group_concat.html) for inspiration

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know what these fields are prefixed with, and that they are the same in every entry, you can use the `FIELD('target phrase', 'string to check')` function to get the locations of the various fields, and then use `SUBSTRING` to remove the bits in-between for your inserts.